# PHP - Array within the same array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

how do I include the same array inside foreach loop and remove the same value inside another array. My PHP skills is not strong and I would like to seek help from the experts here. Please see the scenario below.

```
$array = array("group1","group2","group3","group4");
//Result should be
group1 = group2,group3,group4
group2 = group1,group3,group4
group3 = group1,group2,group4
group4 = group1,group2,group3
```

I am only at:

```
 $array = array('group1','group2','group3','group4');


foreach($array as $value){
  echo '<br>'.$prodfilters.'= <br>';
  foreach($arrayFilter as $xx){
    echo $xx.'<br>';
  }
}
//Result
group1 = group1,group2,group3,group4
group2 = group1,group2,group3,group4
group3 = group1,group2,group3,group4
group4 = group1,group2,group3,group4
//basically repeating itself each value from the outer foreach loop instead of removing the same value from the inner foreach loop.
```

Hope you can help a newbie here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this `group1 = group2,group3,group4` should be a string or an array? Whether it should create multiple arrays OR to update the initial one?

Comment: Hi I updated my question. Apologies for my slow explanation.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I should be able to use it as a variable outside foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a short solution using `array_walk` and `array_diff` functions:

```
$array = ["group1","group2","group3","group4"];
$result = [];

array_walk($array, function($v) use(&$result, $array){
    $result[$v] = array_diff($array, [$v]);   // it can be imploded into a string if needed
});

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [group1] => Array
        (
            [1] => group2
            [2] => group3
            [3] => group4
        )

    [group2] => Array
        (
            [0] => group1
            [2] => group3
            [3] => group4
        )

    [group3] => Array
        (
            [0] => group1
            [1] => group2
            [3] => group4
        )

    [group4] => Array
        (
            [0] => group1
            [1] => group2
            [2] => group3
        )
)
```

Now you can access each item by specifying its "name" as an array key, like `$result['group3']`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$array = ["group1","group2","group3","group4"];
$new = [];
foreach ($array as $key1) {
    $new[$key1] = [];
    foreach ($array as $key2) {
        if ($key1 !== $key2) {
            $new[$key1][] = $key2;
        }
    }
}
print_r($new);
```

Comment: That was fast, and what i was looking for! Thank you @mustafayelmer

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely shure what you want to achieve.
Here an iterative suggestion:

```
foreach($array as $value){
     $result.=$value.' = ';
     foreach($array as $value2){
         if($value2 != $value){
              $result.=$value2.',';
         }
     }
     $result.=rtrim($result,',').'\n'; //replace \n with <br/> for html linefeed
}
echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fun solution because it makes use of:

- [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)
- [anonymous function closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)
- [`use` parent variable scoping](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

And a couple useful array functions:

- [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)
- [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to reset the indices

This will provide separate arrays, each named after their respective values in the master array:

```
<?php
$array = array("group1","group2","group3","group4");

foreach ($array as $element)
  $$element = array_values(array_filter($array,function($item) use ($element){return $item !== $element; }));
```

Now you can use the individual arrays by their index name:

```
print_r($group1);
```

Shows this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => group2
    [1] => group3
    [2] => group4
)
```

And you can see all the variables in the environment with [`get_defined_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php)

```
print_r(get_defined_vars());
```

Shows this in source:

```
[group1] => Array
    (
        [0] => group2
        [1] => group3
        [2] => group4
    )

[group2] => Array
    (
        [0] => group1
        [1] => group3
        [2] => group4
    )

[group3] => Array
    (
        [0] => group1
        [1] => group2
        [2] => group4
    )

[group4] => Array
    (
        [0] => group1
        [1] => group2
        [2] => group3
    )
```